# What is wrong with my thoughts about the dimension of quotient space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Definition quotient space, $V/U$

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Then the quotient space $V/U$ is the set of
all affine subsets of $V$ parallel to $U$. In other words, $V/U = \{v+U: v\in V\}$.

Then if $U$ is a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ containing the origin, then $\mathbb R^3/U$ is the set of all planes in $\mathbb R^3$ parallel to $U$. The dimension of this quotient space should be $2$.

But let $\pi$ be the quotient map from $V$ to $V/U$. $\text{null } \pi = U$, $\text{range  }\pi = V/U$ and $\text{dim } V = \text{dim } U + \text{dim } V/U$.

Then if $U$ is a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ containing the origin, the dimension of $\mathbb R^3/U$ should be $3-2=1$.

What is wrong with my thoughts about the dimension of quotient space?

Thanks

Comment: What is the justification for your statement "The dimension of this quotient space should be 2", after giving the definition? Everything else you wrote seems correct.

Comment: Because they are planes in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: They are indeed planes, but the space of all these planes can be parametrized by a single number, since you already know that they are all parallel. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, I understand, all these planes can be parametrized by a line perpendicular to them.

Comment: Exactly! That should solve your problem. All the best

Comment: @DanLi if you've figured out an answer to your question from the comments then you should post it as an answer

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding of the definition of the quotient space is correct, but your application of the formula for the dimension of the quotient space is incorrect.

The formula for the dimension of the quotient space is indeed:
dim V=dim U+dim V/U

However, this formula only holds when the quotient map is a linear map. In your example, the quotient map is not a linear map, since it takes an affine subset (a plane) to a point in the quotient space (the set of all planes parallel to U).

Therefore, the formula for the dimension of the quotient space does not apply in this case, and the dimension of the quotient space R3/U cannot be computed using this formula.

Instead, you can think of the quotient space R^3/U as a set of points, where each point represents a plane in R3 parallel to U. In this sense, the dimension of R^3/U is indeed 0 since each point in the quotient space represents a single plane, rather than a subspace of dimension greater than 0.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).